# Evaluate Then send HTML From MailApp Emails

Tags: google-apps-script, html-email, template-engine

Have a html file within my google script project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> <?= Sales().yesterday ?></h1>
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can i send that HTML using MailApp?

```
function Email() {     
  function doGet() {
    return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('html')
      .evaluate();
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to:"email",
      subject: 'email',
      htmlBody: doGet()
    });
}
```

When i send email, It does not output the return of Sales() function.

Comment: What/where is Sales()?

Comment: What do you see as final output? Does `Sales()` actually return any value in `yesterday` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function viewSales(){
  var rObj={'yesterday':'$10000.00'};
  return rObj;
}

function sendEmail() {     
  var html='<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"></head><body><h1> <?= viewSales().yesterday ?></h1><h1>Test</h1></body></html>';
  MailApp.sendEmail({to:"email@email.com",subject:"Sales Email",htmlBody: HtmlService.createTemplate(html).evaluate().getContent()});
}
```